# Samsung Galaxy Ace wont connect to my home wifi

Tags: connection-issues

I am trying to connect my new phone to my home wifi, it connects i put the password in, it says remembering connection... authenticating then comes up with disabled. I've tried using the app which said it'd solved the problem but it hadn't. what should i do?

Comment: Does it work on other WiFi networks? Have you tried changing your router settings? What band and protocol is your router using?

Comment: I've only had it a day so as yet have not tried it on other networks - i've followed the directions exactly so i know i'm doing it correctly.The router is (sky broadband) a Netgear and i believe protocol CHAP

Comment: also i haven't changed my router settings as i honestly wouldn't know what to alter!

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear - Is your router using 802.11a, 802.11b, 802.11g, 802.11n, or a combination?  Does it broadcast at the 2.4GHz or 5.0GHz frequency?

Comment: Looks like OP lost interest -- but just in case: There are at least two Q&As here which might prove helpful: [Problem with connection to home Wi-Fi - how to debug?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/problem-with-connection-to-home-wi-fi-how-to-debug) and [Why does Wi-Fi fail to connect to certain public networks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22710/why-does-wi-fi-fail-to-connect-to-certain-public-networks). So please, check them out if the problem still/again exists.

Answer (score 1):

I use to have this problem too. I recommend restarting your router and then try to connect to the Wi-Fi again. Lastly reboot your phone. You can find more instructions here: http://www.technobezz.com/android-wont-connect-to-wi-fi/

I hope this helps to resolve your issue.